# How can I allow player-created content to add morphs to Daz Genesis 8 characters(UE4)?

Tags: unreal-4, skeletal-animation, import

We use Daz Genesis 8 characters in our project. Content creators would load their morphs from Daz to our game. We would like to add these morphs to our characters so they can be modded, edited and stuff. The problem is we already have morphs on our chars, and we don't want to lose them! I simply would like to add morphs to the list of morphtargets so I can expose them to the player!

Can anyone direct me to the right c++ classes, blueprints, git repos, assets or anything to look at?

Thanks